# Radio signals blocked by red bricks / aluminum insulation

Tags: signal, radio

Do red bricks home/building and aluminum insulation diminish the strength of radio signals?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course, for some types of "bricks", some ranges of frequencies, and some values of "diminish".  Just about everything absorbs or reflects some frequencies accross the radio spectrum.

Comment: Doesn't aluminum block EM waves much more than "less" conductive materials like bricks ?

Comment: Depends on the frequency.  If you make the Al thin enough you can get some light through it... you can't see through a brick.  :^)  (I'm talking about very thin Al ~10's of nanometers.)

Comment: If you make a brick thin enough you can see through it.

Comment: @JohnU If you make a brick thin enough to see through, is it still a brick? :)